# Capture Commands running from Clearcase Explorer GUI

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

Can I capture the commands that are running behind actions done in the GUI -Rational ClearCase Explorer -?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the Legacy Unix "xclearcase" tool, the ClearCase explorer GUI does not invoke command line tools by default. So capturing command history is somewhat more challenging.

Can you provide some details on what operations you need to capture? In many cases these can be captured using preop- or postop- triggers (assuming VOB operations).

Answer (score 0):

The ClearCase Exmplorer (pre 8.x) does not have any cleartool tracing logs, as it does mostly direct rpc calls to the ClearCase server.

The ClearTeam Explorer (8.x or 9.X) does [have a tracing log](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684885) which also does *not* show any cleartool commands, but rather Java API calls, and [more explicit error messages as in this ticket](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21663439).
You need to launch CTE in debug mode for that: `ctexplorer -debug`.

Comment: The problem with using the CTE debug option is that you wind up sipping from a firehose. Probably not what you want...